# Loading angular ui-bootstrap with require.js fails unless i rename ui.bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, angular-ui-bootstrap, js-amd

**Summary of code:**

main.js:

```
    require.config({
        paths: {
            'uiBootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min'
        },
        shim: {***},
        priority: ['angular'],
        deps: [
            './bootstrap'
        ]
            });
```

---

bootstrap.js:

```
    define([
        'require',
        'angular',
        ...
    ], function (require, ng) {
        'use strict';
        require([
                'domReady!',
                'uiBootstrap'
                ], function (document) {
                    ng.bootstrap(document, ['app']);...
```

---

app.js:

```
    define([
        'angular',
         ...
    ], function (ng) {
        'use strict';

        return ng.module('app', [
            ...
            'uiBootstrap'
        ]);
    });
```

I was getting a range of differing errors while trying different combinations. Until I went into ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js and actually Replaced All ui.bootstrap to uiBootstrap and modifed the module name reference as seen above. And presto - ui-bootstrap is working fine.

Obviously this is a less than optimal solution.

Can anyone please provide insight why this is occurring and what the better approach to resolve it is, so I don't go public using this source modified ui-bootstrap?

Thank You!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `app.js` when giving the dependencies to `angular` you should give it as `'ui.bootstrap'`(this is the correct module name) and not your custom name which you defined in `main.js`.

So your `app.js` would look like:

```
define([
    'angular',
    'uiBootstrap',
     ...
], function (ng) {
    'use strict';

    return ng.module('app', [
        ...
        'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);
});
```